# Docker-Compose with multible containers connection to wiremock didn't work

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, connection, wiremock

I have a Docker Compose setup with a Spring Boot application, Database and WireMock. While this configuration works fine locally, the Spring Boot app cannot communicate with WireMock when running in Docker Compose. I suspect there might be an issue with how the Spring Boot app reads the myapp_wiremock environment variable or with the communication between containers. Can you please provide guidance on troubleshooting this issue?

[**docker-compose.yml: **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PHdp.png)

[**
application.ymal:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm97M.png)

**The connection between datbase and application is good only the connection to Wiremock don't work. When I write MYAPP_WIREMOCK=http://wiremock:8080/ it didn`t work to**

**This is the error: ** Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [
Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8082/api/getPetStatus": Connection refused] with root cause